# python config of logging module overridden and not adjustable after import some module

Tags: python, logging

I like to set global configuration of logging module,
but after import some module (for e.g. chainer),
it changes and not restored by basicConfig cmd.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
logging.info("TEST(info) before import chainer")
logging.critical("TEST(critical) after import chainer")

import chainer
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
logging.info("TEST(info) after import chainer")
logging.critical("TEST(critical) after import chainer")
```

Output is:

```
INFO: TEST(info) before import chainer
CRITICAL: TEST(critical) after import chainer
TEST(critical) after import chainer
```

How can I keep my configuration?
Using python=3.8.18 and pip install chainer==7.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Do logging configuration *only* in code that runs from a `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause. That way, importing a module won't set/update logging configuration, but running a module as a script will.